# Php and email digital signature problems

Tags: php, email, openssl, digital-signature

I try to digitally sign my emails with php, but I have some problems with it.
I have generated certificate signed with my own CA with open ssl :

```
openssl req -new -nodes -out request.pem -keyout key.pem -days 1098 -config ./openssl.cnf
openssl ca -in request.pem -out cert.pem -config ./openssl.cnf
```

I have generated private key key.pem a signed certificate 04.pem
In doc root of apache I have file  podepsany_email.php and cert + key next to it.

for digital signing I use function openssl_pkcs7_sign().
Code :

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign("./msg.txt", "./signed.txt", "./04.pem" ,"./key.pem", $headers);
```

The result of call my script is error message :

> Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign() [function.openssl-pkcs7-sign]: error
>   getting private key in C:\data\www\podepsany_email.php on line 70

Could please someone give me point how to solve this issue? Thanks

K.

Comment: There aren't any passwords or passphrases set on the files?

Comment: No, key is exported without password. Solvation of this issue is change all file paths in function call to absolute path. Then function run without problems.

Comment: You can put that in an answer and accept it yourself by selecting the tick to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

see the php documentation discussion: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php

you should put "file://" in front of the .pem file names